# sub directory multisite just redirecting to default after first page

Tags: multi-sites

I have a sub directory multisite setup on a sub domain. (locally with mamp everything is running fine), but on my live server, i can only reach the first (home) page of the multisite site, and when going anywhere (q?=user/login), i get directed to the default site.

site is ***dev.mysite.com/www.example.com***

i have softlink in the drupal root - ***www.example.com -> ./***

in sites.php i have

`$sites = array('dev.mysite.com.www.example.com' => 'example.com',);`

and of course the structure is ***sites/example.com***

nothing like a cookie address in the settings... i dont know what else could be wrong. Using the same htaccess, the default, that was working locally for me.

---

i did notice something interesting that could be a clue. I have a logo image embedded in the page template. (`img src="<?php print base_path().path_to_theme(); ?>/img/logo.png"`)

so locally the source prints as:

`img src="/www.mysite.com/sites/example.com/themes/example/img/logo.png"`

and on the server it looks like

`img src="http://dev.mysite.com/www.example.com/sites/example.com/themes/example/logo.png"`

Comment: `i have softlink in the drupal root` - Then you're doing Drupal multisite wrong. Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? For most simple mulitisite set-ups, editing sites.php isn't even necessary, and if you're symlinking than you're almost *certainly* doing it wrong.

Comment: im trying to run a site under dev.mysite.com/www.example.com (because im just develop a site for example.com, so i dont have the domain name). In other words, "www.example.com" could just as well be "coolsiteone".

Comment: Can you create a new subdomain?

Comment: the sub domain is an apache site directive pointing to the directory with the drupal core root. (so yes, i can make another sub domain, and of course point it where i want on my server).

Comment: Okay, then why not just create a new subdomain which uses the same web root as dev.mysite.com? You should be able to do a standard Drupal multisite from there without any symlinking.

Comment: could i guess. ive done this on another server though, and it worked fine. But here i dont know what the deal is. Im still looking at the base_url part..

Comment: ok, i found out its a problem with clean URLs...

Comment: solly me, rewrite module wasn't enabled on my new server :D Thanks for your help in any case @GarrettAlbright !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone happens upon this... This was a case of mod_rewrite not being enabled on the new server. :D

Answer (score 0):

Any caching turned on? (varnish/memcache/...)

If using memcache make sure to separate the memory buckets in each site's config.

```
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'Example_Memcached_Key';
```

Comment: If these are modules then no. And i cleared the cache with devel before exporting the database.